# Image of open disconnected set under continuous injective map is open and disconnected

Tags: real-analysis

This is Problem 4.45 of Apostol's book on Mathematical Analysis:

Given a function $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ which is one-to-one and continuous on $\mathbb{R}^n$ and a set $A$ which is open and disconnected in $\mathbb{R}^n$, prove that $f(A)$ is open and disconnected in $f(\mathbb{R}^n)$.

Any hints on what things I should be looking out for? The nearest thing which I can find online is the so-called Invariance of Domain result, but I don't think I need any high-handed machinery to prove this.